# How to Add call button on a featured image in a wpsite? check the slap king image, there are two buttons on the featured image

Tags: plugins, theme-development, post-thumbnails

[image]
I want to add 2 buttons on the featured image of my WordPress pages. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You can always use your debug tools to see how they're doing it? I'd guess you want a hidden div with the hover content that you show on mouse enter for the image and then hide again when your mouse leaves the div, similar to a tooltip. Then you can put however many buttons you like in that div.

Comment: which debug tools?

Comment: That's Chrome? The three-dots menu, More tools, Developer tools. Or right-click anything on the page and 'Inspect'. Or ctrl-shift-I.